# Redirect to dashboard on refresh if user is logged in React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, local-storage

I work on an application where a user logs in and the token is stored in local storage. I want the homepage to be the login page if the token is not in the local storage or if it is and it's valid to be the protected route "/dashboard". My code is :

```
const App = () => {

  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState<IState["authenticated"]>(false)   

  useEffect ( () => {
    const token: string | null  = localStorage.getItem('token')   
    if (token)
    {
      setAuthenticated(true)
      window.location.assign("/dashboard")
    }
  }, [authenticated])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
        <Route  path="/" element = {<LogIn setAuthenticated={setAuthenticated}/>} />
        <Route path="/signup" element = {<CreateUser />} />
        <Route path="/forgot_password" element ={<ForgotPassword/>} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={authenticated} redirectPath={"/"}
          component = {Dashboard}/>}/>        
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      
    </div>
  )
}


export default App
```

The code doesn't work because the component is re-render continuously. How do I change the main route on refresh in the item is in the local storage without affecting the app when it starts? Thank you

Comment: First thing, in your useEffect, you are re-directing to `/dashboard`. However, in here `<Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={authenticated} redirectPath={"/"}
          component = {Dashboard}/>}/> ` you are again redirecting to `/`. This causes re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Your infinite loop might be caused due to you setting state inside useEffect. You can call setState inside useEffect, just make sure you are not doing that all the time.

```
  useEffect ( () => {
    if(!authenticated){
    const token: string | null  = localStorage.getItem('token')   
    if (token)
    {
      setAuthenticated(true)
      window.location.assign("/dashboard")
    }
    else{
        /* You can have something here */
     }
    }
  }, [authenticated])
```